# How to add another Android API to Xamarin on Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Changing the target framework for the an Android project in Visual Studio gives me a lesser option than using Xamarin Studio editing the same project.

**Visual Studio**

[image]

**Xamarin Studio**

[image]

How can I add a new API, such as 18 or 21, which is missing from the drop down list of available frameworks in Visual Studio?

Comment: Sorry for the obvious, but double check that both Xamarin Studio & Visual Studio are using the same Android SDK location.  Also, double check that Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio are using the same version of Xamarin.Android. It might me that Visual Studio needs an update.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what to do about this?  Thanks.

Comment: No sorry. Haven't touched this subject for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Open project file (.proj) in text editor and edit directly. Look for this:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Comment: My question wasn't about changing it on the project but to add the option to Visual Studio to change it for the project. I can already change it from Xamarin Studio, however, I can't use Visual Studio to compile the same project since that API that I chose in Xamarin Studio isn't available in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry, I missed what you needed.